# Opening Word Document in VBA Results in Empty Variable

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to loop through a folder and open each word document one at a time in VBA. I had the code working, and then I added two more files to the folder. Now it won't open my first file (which I had opened previously. My code is as follows:

```
Sub readEmailsV2()

Dim oFSO As Object, oFolder As Object, oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim pN As Integer
Dim sFileSmall As String, sFileYear As String, sFilePath As String
Dim wapp As Word.Application
Dim wdoc As Word.Document
Dim tabDest As Worksheet
Dim splitVals As Variant
Dim contentsVar As String
Dim jContent As String
Dim pageCount As Integer
Dim fpOpen As Variant


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' USER INPUT
sFileSmall = "C:\Users\rstrott\OneDrive - Research Triangle Institute\Desktop\VBApractice\Docket Index\filesToRead\"


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

' Get variable with filenames from folder (Only contains word docs)
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.getfolder(sFileSmall)
Set tabDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FileContents")
Set wapp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If wapp Is Nothing Then
    Set wapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
tabDest.Cells.Clear

tabDest.Range("a1:a1") = "File Title"
tabDest.Range("b1:b1") = "From:"
tabDest.Range("c1:c1") = "To:"
tabDest.Range("d1:d1") = "cc:"
tabDest.Range("e1:e1") = "Date Sent:"
tabDest.Range("f1:f1") = "Subject:"
tabDest.Range("g1:g1") = "Body:"
tabDest.Range("h1:h1") = "Page Count:"

i = 2

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    
    ' Assign variables
    sFilePath = sFileSmall & oFile.Name
    wapp.Visible = True
    fpOpen = oFile.Path
    Set wdoc = wapp.Documents.Open(sFilePath) ' <---- ERROR HERE: Output is 'Nothing'
    pN = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
    pageCount = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Pages.Count
    
    
    ' Put paragraph contents in cells
    tabDest.Cells(i, 1) = oFile.Name
    tabDest.Cells(i, 2) = wdoc.Paragraphs(2)
    tabDest.Cells(i, 3) = wdoc.Paragraphs(8)
    tabDest.Cells(i, 4) = wdoc.Paragraphs(11)
    tabDest.Cells(i, 5) = wdoc.Paragraphs(5)
    tabDest.Cells(i, 6) = wdoc.Paragraphs(14)
    Dim item As Variant
    For j = 15 To pN
        jContent = wdoc.Paragraphs(j).Range.Text
        If j = 15 And Len(jContent) > 2 Then
            contentsVar = wdoc.Paragraphs(j).Range.Text
        ElseIf Len(jContent) > 2 Then
            contentsVar = contentsVar & Chr(10) & wdoc.Paragraphs(j).Range.Text
        End If
        
        
    Next j
    tabDest.Cells(i, 7) = contentsVar
    tabDest.Cells(i, 8) = pageCount
    
    

    ' Close Word Doc
    wdoc.Close _
        SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    
    i = i + 1
    

Next oFile

End Sub
```

I've tried lots of different things to get it to work again, and I ran out of ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Propably you should clean up your variables. There is `sFilePath` and `fpOpen`. What happens if you use `Set wdoc = wapp.Documents.Open(oFile.Path)`? Furthermore: you are assigning the document to wdoc - there is no need that you use `ActiveDocument` to retrieve para- and page-count.

Comment: @ike Yes, I forgot to mention to ignore the messy variables. I had so many variables in there because I was trying to enter the file path as different variable types (string, variant, etc). Nothing seemed to be working. I changed the paragraph count back to the name of the doc, "wdoc", but I believe I have to keep "ActiveDocument" for pageCount.

Comment: @ike Update: I tried deleting the first file and the script worked. Any idea why some files would be able to be read in and then suddenly not work?

Comment: puh - difficult - when you open the specific document manually do you receive the unsecure file message? Then it makes sense that the doc-variable is nothing. You could check this via the protectedView object. Regarding the usage of your wdoc-variable: you can use it for the pages as well: ``wbdoc.Windows(1).Panes(1).Pages.Count`